# AutoIT3 - get script to run .exes from multiple root directories

Tags: autoit, directory

I have a script that I found online which runs an .exe on my flash drive whenever I plug it in. However I have a second flash drive which obviously has a different letter to the first one, and I want the same script to attempt to try and find the (same) .exe in both flash drives when I only plug on of them in. Currently the code is this:

```
$DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = "0x00008000"
 $WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219
 GUICreate("")
 GUIRegisterMsg($WM_DEVICECHANGE , "MyFunc")
 Func MyFunc($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $WParam, $LParam)
 If $WParam == $DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Then
Run ("J:\DropboxPortableAHK\DropboxPortableAHK.exe")
 EndIf
 EndFunc
 While 1
 $GuiMsg = GUIGetMsg()
 WEnd
Run ("K:\DropboxPortableAHK\DropboxPortableAHK.exe")
 EndIf
 EndFunc
 While 1
 $GuiMsg = GUIGetMsg()
 WEnd
```

Now, I'm not gonna lie, I don't actually have a clue what any of this does, with the sole exception of the Run command. I'm a very novice programmer and I only have experience in Python3, so I tried adding a second run command after the first but it didn't work. I tried Googling the problem, but I couldn't find anything that I recognised as similar to my question. If anybody knows how I could get the same script to detect both drives (J and K), that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Just copy and paste some lines without understanding what they do is not they right way to create working software ;-)
If you are really able to read Python code, you should be able to understand the basic structure of this program even if you don't know what exactly the functions do... anyways, their names are quite obvious. There is a GUI created (even it's never beeing shown) and "MyFunc" registered to be executed whenever the message for a device change occurs. Then it just runs some code, when the specific action of a new device arriving has happened. The infinite loop prevents quitting.

Comment: I'm well aware of that now, but now I have more than a year of programming behind me :P At the time of writing I had been coding in Python for a month and our lecturer hadn't even got to loops yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a quick and dirty solution:
Just double only the first `Run(...)` line and change the drive letter. Nothing will happen, when the path won't be found... but if both are found, both will be run. And remove all the lines after `WEnd`. That's just unnecessary copy'n'paste without knowing what you do ;-)